# can't connect anymore with expo client on ubuntu

Tags: react-native, expo

I had been working on a react-native project for about a week on my main computer, which is Ubuntu. After having some reloading issues, I tried running on my macbook, and that has been working fine. However, I can't get my expo client to connect at all now on my Ubuntu, which is what I'm trying to solve here.

What happens is that I run `npm start` and it starts up normal. When I scan the QR code, it doesn't load and in the "View Error Log" at the bottom it says `Uncaught Error: Packager is not running at http://192.168.1.4:19001` I also try to enter the `exp://192.168.1.4:19000` address it suggests I can enter as the url instead of scanning the QR code. This also gives me the same error.

I noticed the port is different, but even when putting in 19000 it says the packagager is not running on 19001 which is confusing me.

This all started happening after the first time I ran expo on my macbook, which I believe has something to do with this error, but I can't tie it together yet - and maybe it doesn't have anything to do with it. I tried turning off my macbook, turning off my ubunut, turning off my phone, turning off my router, and then hiding in the closet for 5 minutes.

After turning my router, Ubuntu and phone back on and getting the expo packager running on my Ubuntu, the same error persists when trying to connect via the expo client on my phone. This error has not been something temporar - it seemed like one of those that would just go away, but it has been about a week now with this same error.

Any ideas?

Edit: The other thing I've tried is changing the port my expo server is running on by changing the script in package.json. I've tried changing to `PORT=19001 react-native-scripts start` and `react-native-scripts start --port 19001` but neither of those have changed the port according to the server output address after starting up.

Comment: That's super odd. Can you spin up another Ubuntu VM with same conditions and verify there?

Comment: Are you running a firewall? It might be blocking you. Also Expo might be choosing the wrong IP especially if you have other network applications like VBox running, it defaults to the first ipv4 address in the list, sometimes this isn't your wlan IP. Maybe look into that too? Hope you find a solution, this looks annoying.

Comment: @Mirodinho i don't think there's a firewall issue, it was working before ubuntu and working currently serving from the macbook. Will check if there's some other network application running, thanks